# How to keep some deep props in object?

Tags: javascript

How to keep some deep props in object?

Following is a sample object.

```
    const sample_object = {
      prop1: {
        subprop1: {
          anothersubprop1: {
            properties: {realprop: {properties: {type: 'real_value', unwantedProps1: {}, unwantedProps2: {}}}
            $ref: {},
          },
          unwantedAnotherSubProp1: {},
          ...
        },
        unwantedSubProp1: {},
        ...
      },
      unwantedProp1: {},
      prop2: {
        subprop1: {
          anothersubprop1: {
            properties: {realprop: {type: 'real_value'}},
            $ref: {},
          },
          unwantedAnotherSubProp1: {},
          ...
        },
        unwantedSubProp1: {},
        unwantedSubProp2: {},
        subprop2: {
          anothersubprop1: {
            properties: {realprop: {type: 'real_value'}},
            $ref: {},
          },
          anothersubprop2: {
            properties: {
              properties: {realprop: {type: 'real_value'}},
              $ref: {},
            },
            unwantedAnotherSubProp1: {},
            unwantedAnotherSubProp2: {},
            $ref: {},
          },
          ...
        },
        unwantedSubProp3: {},
        unwantedSubProp4: {},
        ...
      },
      unwantedProp2: {},
      prop3: {
        subprop1: {
          anothersubprop1: {
            properties: {realprop: {type: 'real_value'}},
            $ref: {},
          },
        },
        subprop2: {
          anothersubprop1: {
            properties: {},
            $ref: {},
          },
          unwantedAnotherSubProp1: {},
        },
        unwantedSubProp1: {},
        unwantedSubProp2: {},
        ...
      },
      unwantedProp3: {},
...
      properties: {realprop: {type: 'real_value'}},
      $ref: {},
    };
```

How to keep only the following props while removing all others deeply?

```
            properties: {realprop: {type: 'real_value'}},
            $ref: {},
```

**// notice all props sub to the above two props which are unwanted will also get removed.**

Notice also that the in the above two required props we need to replace

```
properties: {realprop: {type: 'real_value'}}
```

into :

```
properties: {realprop: 'real_value', name: 'Real Value', size: 10}
```

So the final required props will have :

```
properties: {realprop: 'real_value', name: 'Real Value', size: 10},
$ref: {},
```

we are adding an extra property called name in here (this will be the sentence case form of the value 'real_value' (from realprop: 'real_value') and also size (this will be a constant for all).

the following is the expected result:

```
 const expected_object = {
      prop1: {
        subprop1: {
          anothersubprop1: {
            properties: {realprop: 'real_value', name: 'Real Value'},
            $ref: {},
          },
          ...
        },
        ...
      },
      prop2: {
        subprop1: {
          anothersubprop1: {
            properties: {realprop: 'real_value', name: 'Real Value', size: 10},
            $ref: {},
          },
          ...
        },
        subprop2: {
          anothersubprop1: {
            properties: {realprop: 'real_value', name: 'Real Value', size: 10},
            $ref: {},
          },
          anothersubprop2: {
            properties: {
              properties: {realprop: 'real_value', name: 'Real Value', size: 10},
              $ref: {},
            },
            $ref: {},
          },
          ...
        },
        ...
      },
      prop3: {
        subprop1: {
          anothersubprop1: {
            properties: {realprop: 'real_value', name: 'Real Value', size: 10},
            $ref: {},
          },
        },
        subprop2: {
          anothersubprop1: {
            properties: {realprop: 'real_value', name: 'Real Value', size: 10},
            $ref: {},
          },
        },
        ...
      },
...
      properties: {realprop: 'real_value', name: 'Real Value', size: 10},
      $ref: {},
    };
```

**If lodash or any other similar library is possible, please suggest** 
**or any custom code**

**UPDATE: I've made a minor update. Please consider that too**

Comment: I;'ve made an update. Please check that.

Answer (score 0):

a recursive approach to solve this problem is to iterate each one of the layers until you get to a property without children .

```
const treeTrim = (obj) => {
    let result = {}
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(e => {
        if (saveList.has(e)) {
            result[e] = obj[e]
        }

        else if (typeof (obj[e] == "object") && Object.keys(obj[e]).length > 0) {
            result[e] = treeTrim(obj[e])
        }
    })
    return result
}

const capitalize = (s) => {
    if (typeof s !== 'string') return ''
    return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)
}

const formatProperties = (obj) => {
    let result = {}
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(e => {

        if (e === "properties" && Object.keys(obj[e]).length > 0) {
            if (obj[e].realprop && obj[e].realprop.type) {
                const value = obj[e].realprop.type
                let capitalizeValue = value.replace("_", " ").split(" ")
                capitalizeValue = capitalizeValue.map(e =>  { return capitalize(e) }).join(" ")
                result[e] = { realprop: value, name: capitalizeValue, size: capitalizeValue.length }
            }
            else {
                result[e] = obj[e]
            }
        }
        else if (typeof (obj[e] == "object") && Object.keys(obj[e]).length > 0) {
            result[e] = formatProperties(obj[e])
        }
    })
    return result
}
```

running example :

```js
const sample_object = {
    prop1: {
        subprop1: {
            anothersubprop1: {
                properties: { realprop: { type: 'real_value' } },
                $ref: {},
            },
            unwantedAnotherSubProp1: {},
        },
        unwantedSubProp1: {},
    },
    unwantedProp1: {},
    prop2: {
        subprop1: {
            anothersubprop1: {
                properties: { realprop: { type: 'real_value' } },
                $ref: {},
            },
            unwantedAnotherSubProp1: {},
        },
        unwantedSubProp1: {},
        unwantedSubProp2: {},
        subprop2: {
            anothersubprop1: {
                properties: { realprop: { type: 'real_value' } },
                $ref: {},
            },
            anothersubprop2: {
                properties: {
                    properties: { realprop: { type: 'real_value' } },
                    $ref: {},
                },
                unwantedAnotherSubProp1: {},
                unwantedAnotherSubProp2: {},
                $ref: {},
            },
        },
        unwantedSubProp3: {},
        unwantedSubProp4: {},
    },
    unwantedProp2: {},
    prop3: {
        subprop1: {
            anothersubprop1: {
                properties: { realprop: { type: 'real_value' } },
                $ref: {},
            },
        },
        subprop2: {
            anothersubprop1: {
                properties: {},
                $ref: {},
            },
            unwantedAnotherSubProp1: {},
        },
        unwantedSubProp1: {},
        unwantedSubProp2: {},
    },
    unwantedProp3: {},
    properties: { realprop: { type: 'real_value' } },
    $ref: {},
};

const saveList = new Set(["$ref", "properties"])



const treeTrim = (obj) => {
    let result = {}
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(e => {
        if (saveList.has(e)) {
            result[e] = obj[e]
        }

        else if (typeof (obj[e] == "object") && Object.keys(obj[e]).length > 0) {
            result[e] = treeTrim(obj[e])
        }
    })
    return result
}

const capitalize = (s) => {
    if (typeof s !== 'string') return ''
    return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)
}

const formatProperties = (obj) => {
    let result = {}
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(e => {

        if (e === "properties" && Object.keys(obj[e]).length > 0) {
            if (obj[e].realprop && obj[e].realprop.type) {
                const value = obj[e].realprop.type
                let capitalizeValue = value.replace("_", " ").split(" ")
                capitalizeValue = capitalizeValue.map(e =>  { return capitalize(e) }).join(" ")
                result[e] = { realprop: value, name: capitalizeValue, size: capitalizeValue.length }
            }
            else {
                result[e] = obj[e]
            }
        }
        else if (typeof (obj[e] == "object") && Object.keys(obj[e]).length > 0) {
            result[e] = formatProperties(obj[e])
        }
    })
    return result
}

console.log(formatProperties(treeTrim(sample_object)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I've made a minor update. Can you please update the code?

Answer (score 0):

An example with lodash function set

```
const removeUnwanted = (obj, props = [], funcs = {}) => {
   const res = {}
   const readProps = (currentObj, path = '') => {
      if (typeof currentObj !== 'object') return 
      for (const key in currentObj) {
         if (props.includes(key)) {
            let value = currentObj[key]
            if (funcs[key]) value = funcs[key](value)
            _.set(res, path + key, value)
         } else {
            readProps(currentObj[key], path + key + '.')
         }
      } 
   }

   readProps(obj)
   return res
}

const transformProperties = (prop) => {
   if (prop.realprop) return { 
      realprop: prop.realprop.type
      size: prop.realprop.type.length
   }
   return prop
}

removeUnwanted(obj, ['properties', 'ref'], { properires: transformProperties })
```

without lodash set function can be something like this

```
function setByPath(obj, path, value) {
  let currentOnj = obj
  const parts = path.split('.')
  const key = parts.pop()
  parts.forEach(p => {
    if (!currentObj[p]) currentOnj[p] = {}
    currentObj = currentObj[p]
  })
  currentObj[key] = value
}
```

example
https://codepen.io/dimoff66/pen/VwejYMy?editors=1112

Comment: Please consider minor updates made: {realprop: 'real_value', name: 'Real Value', size: 10}

Comment: "message": "'_' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.",

Comment: @mex, considered, how to set name property you can find yourself i guess

Comment: @mex, please find yourself how to manage l;odash module or just write set function yourself. It is not a complicated task

Comment: It's from lodash. Right. I thought it was a placeholder.

Comment: But this is not removing unwanted props deeply nested.

Comment: It is only removing from the first level

Comment: What if we have another level of props deep below properties;

Comment: @mex, supposed to remove from any level, let me check

Comment: It is only removing first level

Comment: for example what if we have another level like this :
properties: {realprop: {properties: {type: 'real_value', unwantedProps: {}}}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215860/discussion-between-mex-and-dmitry-reutov).

Comment: @mex, it works perfectly well, i added link to codepen example